# mvvmcrosscore valueconverters not invoked

Tags: mvvmcross

I had written these two converters but they are not' invoked... Do I need to add extra piece of code in minisetup.cs file for them to work

```
public class BooleanNegationValueConverter : IMvxValueConverter
    {
        #region IMvxValueConverter implementation

        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (!(Boolean)(value));
        }

        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        #endregion
```

I am using this in the usual way

```
set.Bind(toolbar.hidden).To(vm => vm.toolbarstate).WithConversion("BooleanNegation");
```

I am using MvvmcrossCore

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own..

```
//Register the converters
        IMvxValueConverterRegistry converterRegistery = ioc.Resolve<IMvxValueConverterRegistry>();
        converterRegistery.AddOrOverwrite ("BooleanNegationConverter", new BooleanNegationValueConverter ());
        converterRegistery.AddOrOverwrite ("ExchangeRatetoStringValueConverter", new ExchangeRatetoStringValueConverter ());
```

Comment: From the [MVVMCross wiki on value converters](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters) at least I get the impression that this registration should be made automatically in the setup. Any thoughts on this?